# Unable to convert SharedArray to Array automatically in Julia?

Tags: types, casting, type-conversion, julia

So I am using a library in Julia that is complaining because it is unable to convert a SharedArray to a normal Array. I tried even explicitly providing a convert function into Base.convert() to see if I could resolve it, but it has failed. I am very confused about why my conversion does not work.

Here is the conversion function:

```
convert(::Type{Array{Int64,1}}, x::SharedArray{Int64, 1}) = x.s


ERROR: TypeError: ensure_loaded: in typeassert, expected Array{Int64,1}, got SharedArray{Int64,1}
 in rmse at .../.julia/v0.4/RecSys/src/als-wr.jl:105
```

I've already filled a [ticket](https://github.com/abhijithch/RecSys.jl/issues/31) with the library, but there really should be a way to file a conversion to fix these issues, and I am little confused about why it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: here is a minimum working example of the issue. May it serve as an excellent teaching tool about the difference between conversion and promotion:

```
function foo(input :: Vector{64})
  nothing
end

#IN some other file...
function shoo(some_array :: SharedArray{Int64, 1}) #Still an error even with the conversion
  a = some_array :: Vector
  foo(a)
end

import Base.convert
convert(::Type{Vector}, x::SharedArray{Int64, 1}) = x.s

some_array =  S = SharedArray(Int, 64, init = S -> S[Base.localindexes(S)] = myid())
shoo(some_array)
```

Comment: Wait, why is it necessary to add to `Base.convert()` in this case?  You can already do `A = SharedArray(Int64, 5); B = convert(Array{Int64}, A);`

Comment: Because it gives an error and adding Base.convert() ensures that Julia can automatically cast it to the proper type without any warnings. Convert functions can be applied automatically, and I am confused why it is not being applied automatically in this case.

Comment: A MWE would be great here.

Comment: This really would be nice with a MWE. It would be a good reference question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Julia does not have automatic conversion.

[Docs:](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/conversion-and-promotion/)

> ... Julia falls into the “no automatic promotion” category: ... the arguments of functions are never automatically converted.

Sometimes it might look like automatic conversions are being done,
but they are not. It is just that a method is defined to do the convert.
Often as a fallback, for `::Any` typed parameters (That is how it works for arithmetic operators).

---

#### For example:

There is a defined method: `Base.convert(::Type{Float64}, Int64)`

```
Base.convert(Float64, 6)
> 6.0
```

That works.

Type-asserts are assertions that things have a particular type.
written `val::Type`.
They can be used to encourage type stability, and help out with inference.
And to enforce (as assertions) that things are as you expect.

Now lets do some assignments, with **type-asserts**.

```
a = 6 ::Float64
>ERROR: TypeError: typeassert: expected Float64, got Int64

a = 6.0 ::Float64
>6.0

a = convert(Float64,6) ::Float64
>6.0
```

So simply defining the conversion between the types is not enough for it to be called.
A call `convert` needs to be added to the code prior to the type assert, for a conversion to be done.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation; I am working with the library maintainers now to fix the issue, but thank you so much for helping me understand the capabilities of Julia.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Array() function. That worked for me.

Comment: My question is not HOW to convert it to array, my question is why the convert function is not automatically converting it and still yielding a type assert error.